# Mis-understanding object extension

Tags: php, object, extends

Consider the code:

```
    class A {
        function x(): string { return 'X'; }
        function dump(): void {
            error_log('In A: ' . $this->x());
        }
    }
    class B extends A {
        function x(): string { return 'XXX'; }
        function dump(): void {
            error_log('In B: ' . $this->x());
            parent::dump();
        }
    }
    $a = new A();
    $b = new B();
    $a->dump();
    $b->dump();
```

This results in:

```
   In A: X
   In B: XXX
   In A: XXX
```

, where I would expect the result to be:

```
   In A: X
   In B: XXX
   In A: X
```

What is it that I do not understand?

Comment: PHP knows that `$this` is still an instance of `B`. If you called `parent::x()` from a method of `B`, it would know to refer to the base method.

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems correct. You've overridden the method, and are calling it within the context of `B` still.

If you want `A` to use its own version of the method, you can use this:

`error_log('In A: ' . self::x());`